# codeigniter: complex mysql select is not working anymore

Tags: codeigniter

I have this simple code that works fine:

```
$sQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT domain FROM domainmarket.inventory_domains");
```

but when i use this

```
$sQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT
                              invDom.domain,
                              sldPhr.phrase1
                            FROM domainmarket.inventory_domains invDom
                              INNER JOIN lux.domain_info domInfo
                                ON invDom.domain = domInfo.domain
                              JOIN lux.sld_stats sldStats
                                ON domInfo.sld = sldStats.sld
                              JOIN lux.sld_phrase sldPhr
                                ON sldPhr.sld = sldStats.sld");
```

or this

```
$sQuery = $this->db->query("SELECT
                              invDom.domain,
                              sldPhr.phrase1
                            FROM domainmarket.inventory_domains invDom
                              INNER JOIN lux.domain_info domInfo
                                ON invDom.domain = domInfo.domain
                              JOIN lux.sld_stats sldStats
                                ON domInfo.sld = sldStats.sld
                              JOIN lux.sld_phrase sldPhr
                                ON sldPhr.sld = sldStats.sld
                            WHERE SOUNDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(invDom.domain, ".", 1)) = SOUNDEX('love')
                            ORDER BY invDom.appraised_price DESC");
```

it already gives this error:

```
Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 33554432 bytes exhausted (tried to
allocate 32 bytes) in
C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_test\system\database\drivers\mysql\mysql_result.php
on line 152
```

or

> Error Number: 1064
>         You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that     corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>     near ' 1) ) = SOUNDEX('love') ORDER BY invDom.app' at line 5
>         SELECT    invDom.domain,      sldPhr.phrase1    FROM domainmarket.inventory_domains invDom    INNER JOIN lux.domain_info
>   domInfo
>         ON invDom.domain = domInfo.domain     JOIN lux.sld_stats sldStats
>         ON domInfo.sld = sldStats.sld     JOIN lux.sld_phrase sldPhr
>         ON sldPhr.sld sldStats.sld  WHERE SOUNDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(invDom.domain,, 1)) = SOUNDEX('love')     ORDER
>   BY invDom.appraised_price DESC  Filename:
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\ci_test\system\database\DB_driver.php    Line Number:
>   33

respectively. Both of these codes work fine in heidiSQL though.. why am i getting this error in codeigniter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a quoting issue. You wrap your query in `"` and then use them in your query.

```
$sQuery = $this->db->query("
SELECT invDom.domain, sldPhr.phrase1 FROM domainmarket.inventory_domains invDom
INNER JOIN lux.domain_info domInfo ON invDom.domain = domInfo.domain
JOIN lux.sld_stats sldStats ON domInfo.sld = sldStats.sld
JOIN lux.sld_phrase sldPhr ON sldPhr.sld = sldStats.sld
WHERE SOUNDEX( SUBSTRING_INDEX(invDom.domain, '.', 1) ) = SOUNDEX('love')
ORDER BY invDom.appraised_price DESC");
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using double commas in your query use single comma because it is conflicting.

```
SELECT
  invDom.domain,
  sldPhr.phrase1
FROM domainmarket.inventory_domains invDom
  INNER JOIN lux.domain_info domInfo
    ON invDom.domain = domInfo.domain
  JOIN lux.sld_stats sldStats
    ON domInfo.sld = sldStats.sld
  JOIN lux.sld_phrase sldPhr
    ON sldPhr.sld = sldStats.sld
WHERE SOUNDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(invDom.domain, '.', 1)) = SOUNDEX('love')
ORDER BY invDom.appraised_price DESC
```